# How to config ADODB to connect Oracle with Service Name

Tags: php, oracle, connection, adodb

I have a problem with my ADODB connection to Oracle with service name. 
Here is my connection to my Oracle server 
[image]

And here is my code

```
$dbhostname     = "10.0.4.51";
$dbusername     = "user1";
$dbpassword     = "user1";
$port           = "1521";
$db   = ADONewConnection('oci8');
$cstr = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$dbhostname)(PORT=$port))
        (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$tnsname)))";
$db->Connect($cstr, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die('db not available');
```

But I still can't do anything with my query due to this connection 
If any suggestion, I'm fully thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but I have two thoughts.

1. Try using Oracle's EZconnect connection string and let Oracle figure it all out.  In your case it would be:

   `10.0.4.51:1521/devoltp`
2. I noticed your connection dialog used Service name, but in your connections string you specified SID.  Change "SID" in your `$cstr` to "SERVICE NAME"

[EZ Connect Examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#NETAG1517)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple class

```
class AdoConnection {

    public $dbh;

    public function __construct() {
        include_once '../adoconnection/adodb5/adodb.inc.php'; // include your adodb.inc.php file

        $server = "127.0.0.1";
        $user   = "USER/SCHEMA/Database";
        $pwd    = "password";
        $db     = "SID OR Service_Name";

        $this->dbh = NewADOConnection('oci8');
        $this->dbh->Connect(FALSE, $user, $pwd, '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ' . $server. ')(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ' . $db . ') (SID = ' . $db . ')))');
    }

    public function select($sql) {
        $result = $this->dbh->Execute($sql);
        $result = $result->GetRows();
        return $result;
    }

    public function insert($sql) {
        $result = $this->dbh->Execute($sql);
        return $result;
    }
}

$dbh = new AdoConnection();

$dbh->select($sql);
$dbh->insert($sql);
```

Just keep your error_reporting and display_errors On to see the errors.